# How to format time for QuadrigaCX API 'transactions' method

Tags: node.js

I am working with the [QuadrigaCX](https://www.quadrigacx.com/api_info) API.

They have a method 'transactions', with the docs as such:

```
Transactions
GET https://api.quadrigacx.com/v2/transactions
List of recent trades

Params:

book - book to return orders for (optional, default btc_cad)
time - time frame for transaction export ("minute" - 1 minute, "hour" - 1 hour). Default: hour.
Result

Returns descending JSON list of transactions. Every transaction (dictionary) contains:

date - unix timestamp date and time
tid - transaction id
price - BTC price
amount - BTC amount
```

I've personally never seen a time parameter laid out like that before. When I format the parameter as `{ 'time' : 'hour' }` it works, as well as `{ 'time' : 'minute' }` , but I can't get multiple hours, and `{'time' : 'day'}` doesn't work.

I've tried:

```
{'time':'2hour'}
{'time':'2 hours'}
{'time':'2 hour'}
{'time': {'hour' : 2}}
{'time': 'hours 2'}
{'time': 'hour 2'}
```

Among other combos.

1) Has anyone ever seen this before?

2) Any ideas on different combinations?

In the meantime I've reached out to the company and some library authors but it may be a while since I hear from anyone considering it's Friday night.

**Update:** I've heard back from one of the library authors who asked support about this, and it turns out the API only supports those two options, minute and hour. Really bad design since they're both pretty useless haha. I was going to delete this question but I'll leave it up just in case anyone else encounters this problem.

Comment: The Unix time now (a few seconds ago) is 1439608894. You can get it with 'Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)'. I don't understand what exactly you need to do, can you please explain further if above doesn't help.

Comment: Just updated the question with what I ended up finding out. Turns out the API is essentially useless and only takes those two parameters. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess since I don't know this API, but it seems it's stating to pass either minute or hour for the time parameter only like you said; i.e. send

```
{"time":"hour"}
```

for hourly transactions.

Perhaps it doesn't support other time parameters.

Comment: Turns out it only supports either 'minute' or 'hour'. Which is pretty funny. I'll wait for you to see this response but then I am going to delete this question.

Comment: @mrmayfield Leave it up in case anybody else encounters this. That's the awesomeness of SO.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the question with some further info and will leave this up for anymore lost souls haha. Cheers.